# Image slide not behaving as expected with CSS

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have tried to incorporate some code for an image slideshow into my site, but the existing CSS is causing the slideshow not to work as expected.

When I take the slideshow code out of the CSS, it appears as one image element on the screen that changes its img src every 2 seconds, which is the proper behavior.

When I put the code inside the CSS, two different image elements appear on the screen inline. I have played around with the CSS all day and can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I'm sure it's something simple. Any help would be welcome.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds}
```

```css
#banner .content .image {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 18em;
}

#banner .content .image img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <header>
      <h2>header text</h2>
      <p>more text<br />
      </p>
    </header>
    <span class="image"><img class="mySlides" src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" 
        /></span>
    <span class="image"><img class="mySlides" src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" 
        /></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example code, your JavaScript is missing a closing brace (the closing  brace is technically within a JavaScript comment). Once I cleaned that up, everything appears to be working.

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  myIndex++;
  if (myIndex > x.length) {
    myIndex = 1
  }
  x[myIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds}
}
```

```css
#banner .content .image {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 18em;
  margin-left: 3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 18em;
}

#banner .content .image img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header>
    <h2>header text</h2>
    <p>more text<br />
    </p>
  </header>
  <span class="image"><img class="mySlides" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="" 
    /></span>
  <span class="image"><img class="mySlides" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="" 
    /></span>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha59cz1r/)

Comment: i was gonna answer but decided not to because your pictures are actual cute cat pictures

Comment: @soulshined [{placekitten}](https://placekitten.com/) is one of the best websites, ever.

Comment: That must have happened when I copied the code into Stack. The bracket is correct on my site. My problem is still occurring. I think it has to do with the CSS code. Like I said, when I take the slideshow out of the CSS, it works correctly. But I need it inside the CSS so that it looks nice and formatted like the rest of the site.

Comment: @dlc3172 I understand, but can't help you further with the code you've provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your JS:
The last inline comment is disabling the closing bracket of the function.

```
// Change image every 2 seconds}
                             ^^^^^
```

Just remove the comment and your code will work.

Comment: Or put the brace on a new line

Comment: That must have happened when I copied the code into Stack. The bracket is correct on my site. My problem is still occurring. I think it has to do with the CSS code. Like I said, when I take the slideshow out of the CSS, it works correctly. But I need it inside the CSS so that it looks nice and formatted like the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to wrap BOTH images in only one span

```
<span class="image"><img class="mySlides" src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="mySlides" src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></span>
```